# What are the "musical toys"?

Tags: disney-infinity-2.0

I have been happily customising My INterior.  But Cinderella just asked me to put a "musical toy" in my house - I've looked through all the options, and nothing seemed remotely musical.

What qualifies for this challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a grand piano that can be purchased from the toy store: that is what Cinderella wants